# UIPanGesture ignore outside of of mask with CAShapeLayer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, masking, uipangesturerecognizer, cashapelayer

I ran into this problem, I have 27 UIView's laying on top of each other, with exactly the same frame, visually they are laying next to each other, visual respresentation:
[image]

So the frame for all of them is the big yellow square. They get masked using a CAShapeLayer (the colored triangles). I add a UIPanGesture to all of them (not sure this is the best way to do it), and I want to determine on which one the user panned. Of course (obviously), only the top one is accessible, and always is the view in the UIPanGesture. How do I determine on which one of the UIView's the finger was panning? A for loop seems expensive too.. Or am I approaching this wrong?

This is the code for creating all of them and handling the pan gesture:
[Gist to code](https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/dfacf04e71e8bc456b73)

Sender to tag is always 27 though, of course... No clue how to solve this one guys! Anyone a clue?

Comment: Made a little bit of progress, I can determine which one is tapped and which one not using hitTest withEvent: [Gist to code](https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/0610543dac84297c9c41)

The problem is though this is not reacting to the pan gesture, so it get's called once and that's probably not even because of that pan gesture but just a default tap recognizer.. Anyone a clue how to continue?

Comment: You could scale it down to this, which CAShapeLayer was panned on in the panned: handler. The shape layers are drawn in drawRect: [Gist to code](https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/aea8e21dd83f8a2b2b41)

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out!

I moved everything into a custom UIView, where in draw rect I draw all the triangles using CAShapeLayers, add a UIPanGesture to it self, and in the gesture handler you can check in a for loop with CGPathContainsPoint if that layer contains the gesture point!

[Solution code snippet](https://gist.github.com/thomasdegry/fab0354150e6441249eb)

Hope this helps someone!